# Showing DC bar chart only after on renderlet function is called, and not on render.

Tags: dc.js

I am modifying the bar size and position using attr.
However the chart attributes are only available after the chart gets rendered.

So I am doing the modification on the fuction 
chart.on("renderlet.somename", function (chart) {// modification });

My problem is this looks odd, as the chart gets rendered first then the modifications are applied and it all appears on the page.

I want that the chart should only be visible after the modifications has been applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to write that you could use the [`pretransition` event](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor), since this fires after everything has been rendered/redrawn, before transitions start.

But you are correct that the bar width is not publicly accessible (it should be!) and you can't read it from the bars until they have transitioned.

So, as you suggested, you could instead hide the whole chart using CSS:

```
<div id="test" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
```

And then show it at the start of your renderlet:

```
chart.on('renderlet', function(chart) {
  d3.select('div#test').style('visibility', 'visible');
```

To eliminate the pause, you could also disable transitions for this chart when you initialize it;

```
chart
  .transitionDuration(0)
```

And re-enable them in your renderlet:

```
chart
  .on('renderlet', function(chart) {
    d3.select('div#test').style('visibility', 'visible');
    chart.transitionDuration(750); // default value
```

Here's a demo, using a fiddle demonstrating error bars (which also need the bar width): http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/cw86goxy/32/